# How to work with a PostgreSQL XML field with Hibernate?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I want to read and write my XML fields in my PostgreSQL table with JPA. 
There is a Types.SQLXML in JDBC but I cannot find the corresponding type I would use in Java to make Hibernate validate the field properly.

I tried String but now I get a SQLXML is not VARCHAR error message from the hibernate validator.

Can somebody give advise for best practice?

The application must also be able to run with Oracle.

Using Document (DOM) as type would be overkill since I do not always need to process the XML field.

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable (
    ID numeric(20,0) NOT NULL,
    -- snip
    METADATA XML, 
    -- snip
);
```

I use Spring Boot 2.2.0 and Hibernate 5.x for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a [`Types.SQLXML`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#SQLXML) in JDBC but I cannot find the corresponding type I would use in Java

You should use the [`java.sql.SQLXML`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html) interface.